# Parse associative array to display all values according to another index's value

Tags: php, html, html-table, associative-array

I have a mySQL table and when I fetch the rows as an associative array,
I already have the table and everything created. I'm just not sure how to parse the associative array so that I can display the  in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly certain there are probably easier ways to go about this. But you could use a `foreach` and check if the current array value first even has the disk key on it and if it does, add it to a new array with the disk name as the key.

```php
$parsed_disks = [];

foreach ($unparsed_disks as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists('s3_dir_name', $value)) {
        $parsed_disks[$value['s3_dir_name']][] = $value;
    } else {
        $parsed_disks['UnkownDisk'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

I don't know the variable name for the array so I'm using `$unparsed_disks` as a placeholder. Note that this method won't sort the new array in any alphabetical or numerical order since the insertion is based on the old array.

This will produce the following structure in the `$parsed_disks` array.

```php
array (
  'FileDrop1626801' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'sender_id' => '123',
      'sender_email' => 'john.doe@gmail.com',
      'receiver_id' => '789',
      'receiver_email' => 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
      'file_name' => 'form.txt',
      's3_dir_name' => 'FileDrop1626801',
    ),
  ),
  'FileDrop1626809' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'sender_id' => '123',
      'sender_email' => 'john.doe@gmail.com',
      'receiver_id' => '405',
      'receiver_email' => 'john.smith@gmail.com',
      'file_name' => 'form.txt',
      's3_dir_name' => 'FileDrop1626809',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'sender_id' => '123',
      'sender_email' => 'john.doe@gmail.com',
      'receiver_id' => '789',
      'receiver_email' => 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
      'file_name' => 'form.txt',
      's3_dir_name' => 'FileDrop1626809',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Which you can then iterate over, with the first iteration going into each **disk** in the array and the second iteration into each file transaction found in that **disk**. As demonstrated in the following [demo](https://3v4l.org/atqMp).

Comment: Thanks Kim! You mentioned there are probably easier way to do this. Do you know any other ways? Because I do want to make this more efficient. Having 3 foreach loops might be a little inefficient.